# 'str' object has no attribute 'key' django drf

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have this model city and trying to get foreign table data

models.py:

```
class City(BaseModel):
      name = models.CharField(_("City Name"), max_length=80, null=False, blank=False)
      state_name = models.ForeignKey(State, to_field="uid", on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, max_length=55, null=False, blank=False)
      city_type = models.ForeignKey(TypeOfCity, to_field="key", on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, max_length=15, null=False, blank=False)
      city_tier = models.ForeignKey(CityTier, to_field="key", on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, max_length=10, null=False, blank=False)
      status = models.SmallIntegerField(_("Status: 1 for Active; 0:Inactive"), default=1)



class TypeOfCity(models.Model):
      key = models.CharField(verbose_name=_("key"), max_length=15, unique=True)
      value = models.CharField(verbose_name=_("value"), unique=True, max_length=15)
      status = models.SmallIntegerField(_("status:1 for Active; 0: Inactive"), default=1)
```

views.py:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def cityFetch(request):
    try:
       data =decode_data(request.data.copy())
       try:      
          queryset = City.objects.filter(uid=data['uid']).values('name','city_type','city_type__value','status')
          serializer_obj = CitySerializer(queryset,many=True)
          return CustomeResponse(request=request, comment="Get Single City", message="Get Single City", data=json.dumps(serializer_obj.data, cls=UUIDEncoder), status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
      except City.DoesNotExist:
          return CustomeResponse(request=request, comment="City Not Found", message="City Not Found",data=json.dumps({}, cls=UUIDEncoder), status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, validate_errors=1)
    except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    error_str = UID_KEY_IS_MISSING if type(e) is KeyError else UID_IS_NOT_VALID
    return CustomeResponse(request=request, log_data=json.dumps(str(e), cls=UUIDEncoder), comment=error_str, message=error_str, data=json.dumps({}, cls=UUIDEncoder), status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, validate_errors=1)
```

I am getting this queryset:

```
<QuerySet [{'name': 'test', 'city_type': 'normal_city', 'city_type_id__value': 'Normal City', 'status': 1}]>
```

but maybe it's trying to find the key and I am getting this error:
**'str' object has no attribute 'key'**

```
def decode_data(data): 
    try:      
       if data.get('encoded_data', None)=="yes":          
           try:
             output = ast.literal_eval(decrypt(data.get('data', None)).decode('utf-8'))
           except Exception as e:               
             output = json.loads(decrypt(data.get('data', None)).decode('utf-8'))      
      else:
    return output
   except Exception as e:
         output = data.get('data', None)
    return output
...
```

Comment: Could you please show what is happening inside `decode_data` and what is the type of `data`?

Comment: i am just trying to get data from postman like this {"data":{
 
 
"uid":"7d12669a-f195-4544-b760-0a6451d8ccc9"
 
   
}, "encoded_data":"yes"}

Comment: Sorry, this does not answer my question.

Comment: see edits...........................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `CitySerializer` gets the key `city_type`, it presumes that `city_type` is a `TypeOfCity` instance. Yet in your queryset `city_type` is merely a string. The error you have basically says "The serializer expected the `key` attribute from `TypeOfCity` class to be present, but it's not".

So before passing on the queryset to the serializer, turn `city_type` into a `TypeOfCity` instance first:

```py
queryset = City.objects.filter(uid=data['uid']).values('name','city_type','city_type__value','status')

cities = []
for city in queryset:
  city.city_type = TypeOfCity.objects.get(value=city.city_type)  # this line largely depends on your code but you should get the gist
  cities.append(city)

serializer_obj = CitySerializer(cities,many=True)
```

You can make the serializer do this work for you. Use [nested serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-nested-objects) and make them [writable](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations).

Comment: 'dict' object has no attribute 'city_type__value'

Comment: how can  use nested serializer

Comment: when i am using get method without values im getting only pk from foreign table is there any way to get all values from foreign table with get method

Comment: @afk This is strange. You should be able to get the whole object with all the values, see the reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#get

Nested serializers: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-nested-objects

Comment: @afk if there's a different error, it's a topic for a different question (this is a SO rule)

Comment: its same AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'key'

Comment: i was trying to loop over queryset and add the item to new list

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help you with that. I asked the moderator to remove "accepted answer" tick from my answer. Feel free to update your question.